# Get for each year how many employees (male and female) were hired

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using the datacharmer test_db database to make this query. (Scheme: https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1200/0*T4jknBaeaS3y0nKr.png)

I want to show for each year how many employees, male and female, were hired. I mean the first time they were added to a department.

This is the query I have, however I don't want to show the MIN(from_date) field, is there a better solution?

```
SELECT year(from_date) hired_year , COUNT(de.emp_no), MIN(from_date), gender 
FROM dept_emp de
INNER JOIN employees e
ON e.emp_no =  de.emp_no
GROUP BY gender, hired_year
ORDER BY hired_year
```

Dept_emp table:

```
emp_no  dept_no from_date   to_date
10010   d004    1996-11-24  2000-06-26
10010   d006    2000-06-26  9999-01-01
10011   d009    1990-01-22  1996-11-09
10012   d005    1992-12-18  9999-01-01
10013   d003    1985-10-20  9999-01-01
10014   d005    1993-12-29  9999-01-01
```

Expected result

```
year    count   gender
1985    10992   M
1985    7388    F
1986    12134   M
1986    8020    F
1987    12319   M
1987    8115    F
1988    12362   M
1988    8374    F
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: What is wrong with your query? Why can't you just remove that column?

Comment: @jarlh do those tables help you?

Comment: @SalmanA How do I make sure am I counting the first time an employee was added to a department?

Comment: So one employee could be added to same department multiple times?

Comment: No, an employee can be added to different departments, but I want to count only the first time. Does the MIN function work the way I want to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need an additional `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT YEAR(first_date), gender, COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT emp_no, MIN(from_date) AS first_date
    FROM dept_emp
    GROUP BY emp_no
) AS g
JOIN employees AS e ON g.emp_no = e.emp_no
GROUP BY YEAR(first_date), gender
```

But I suppose you could simply use the `hire_date` if the employee is put into a department on the same date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT year(de.from_date) hired_year , Count(*) as Count,e.gender
       FROM dept_emp de INNER JOIN 
       employees e
       ON e.emp_no =  de.emp_no
       GROUP BY hired_year,e.gender
       Order BY hired_year;
```